Azure Data Factory Copy Data activity not working
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. In Azure Data Factory I would like to write a var or a record in a file in Azure Blob. I am using Copy Data Activity (see below). The Source file is a dummy file also stored in Azure Blob. The Sink is another file csv stored in Azure Blob.
All seems fine as the file is created in the correct dinamic path, a columnt header is added (FirstCol) but not the content (hello):




Any hint?

ok I think I found the issue. Seems that the dummy file should contain at least one header + value content.
